# Oracle SQL - Unable to Update when using WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I am trying to update a column based on virtual dataset created via a WITH statement.  I have simplified the statement as much as possible to get to the root issue.   It appears that UPDATE does not work when using a WITH statement, but I can't believe this is accurate.  The error I am getting is

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Here is my SQL statement.

```
with TEMP1 as (
   select  NN_NAME
   from SMB.ACCOUNTS
)   

update SALES_PLAY_MATRIX_WORKING
set FY16_FOCUS = 'Y' where NN_NAME in ( select TEMP1.NN_NAME from TEMP1)
```

If I convert the 2nd portion of the statement to just a pure SELECT, it works...

```
with TEMP1 as (
      select  NN_NAME
      from SMB.ACCOUNTS
)   

(
    select TEMP1.NN_NAME 
    from TEMP1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, `with` does not go just at the beginning of a query.  It can go before any `select`.  So:

```
update SALES_PLAY_MATRIX_WORKING
    set FY16_FOCUS = 'Y'
    where NN_NAME in (
        with TEMP1 as (
              select NN_NAME
              from SMB.ACCOUNTS
             )
        select TEMP1.NN_NAME 
        from TEMP1
       );
```

Comment: Even ANSI SQL compliant. (Feature T121, "WITH (excluding RECURSIVE) in query expression".)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest go for nested query that may solve your issue

```
UPDATE SALES_PLAY_MATRIX_WORKING
SET FY16_FOCUS = 'Y' 
WHERE NN_NAME IN ( SELECT NN_NAME FROM SMB.ACCOUNTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO SALES_PLAY_MATRIX_WORKING dst
USING ( SELECT NN_NAME FROM SMB.ACCOUNTS ) src
ON    ( dst.NN_NAME = src.NN_NAME )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET FY16_FOCUS = 'Y';
```

or more simply:

```
MERGE INTO SALES_PLAY_MATRIX_WORKING dst
USING SMB.ACCOUNTS src
ON    ( dst.NN_NAME = src.NN_NAME )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET FY16_FOCUS = 'Y';
```